# Master Page não aparece na lista quando tento associá-la a uma view

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Estou utilizando o Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 e criei um projeto C# ASP.NET MVC 4.

Criei uma *Master Page* no diretório de *Views*, chamada `Modelo.master`. Em seguida criei um *Controller* no diretório `Controllers`, e novamente uma *View* que exibisse a saída do *Controller*.

Entretanto, na tela de criação de *Views* onde o programa pede para selecionar uma *Master Page* ou layout para utilizar como base da página eu não consigo visualizar a *Master Page* que criei. O arquivo `Modelo.master` nem aparece na lista.

O que poderia ser?

Comment: Você está usando Razor?

Comment: Sim, estou utilizando Razor. Por que? Ele nao me deixa visualizar a master page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Razor, o modelo de `Master Page` não é usado. O que existe são arquivos de **Layout**, usados pela `View` para se construir.

Diferentemente das *Master Pages*, em que se especificava as seções de conteúdo utilizando um conjunto de tags próprio, o Razor utiliza o HTML puro, processando as notações e devolvendo mais HTML. A abordagem é mais simples e menos propensa a erros da parte do servidor.

Normalmente o arquivo de Layout da visão principal (ou seja, a que abre num navegador de computador) fica dentro de `Views\Shared` com o nome de `_Layout.cshtml`, mas nada lhe impede de modificar esse nome. Nesse diretório devem ser colocados outros arquivos de Layout comuns ao sistema. Layouts que sejam próprios de determinadas *Views* pertencentes a um *Controller* podem ficar no diretório específico dessas *Views*.

O *Wizard* que você executou apenas gera uma *View* com a seguinte declaração, que é totalmente opcional:

```cs
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Caminho/Da/Minha/View/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Essa declaração também é encontrada na View especial `_ViewStart.cshtml`, que inicia um Layout padrão caso nenhum Layout seja especificado:

```cs
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```